# permission denied and could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, github

While uploading source code on Git from Ubuntu Terminal,Github gives error permission denied (public key). Could not read from remote repository.

[image]

Comment: The error can be caused due to different reasons, please check this link https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/error-permission-denied-publickey.

Comment: Hi TCOA55_Sanjay Kshetry, welcome to SO. Read the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how you can improve your question. Currently this question shows no research effort, you can do better.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, remove the .git folder from the location
Run commad

```
git init
git remote add <url> origin master
```

Use the url with https not the ssh unless you configured ssh in github.

```
git add .
git commit -m "Initial Init"
git push origin master
```

Now a popup should be opened asking for username and password. Enter them, the code should be pushed to the respective repo.